# How to integrate MQTT and Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I've got a device that communicate via MQTT.
My device have a MQTT server:

```
Host:   node02.myqtthub.com:1883
Client ID:   name****
user:   *****
pass:   ****
Subscribe Topic: GETTO/304470****tx
Publish Topic: GETTO/304470****rx
```

For example with MQTTBox software in Windows if I Publish Payload `"$ST"` it return: `"$SA,277,1,1,105,280,0,0,0000,000,180,05.2,2".`

I want to have this line `"$SA,277,1,1,105,280,0,0,0000,000,180,05.2,2"` on my Google Sheet's cell.
Is possible to integrate it with App Script?

Comment: If you're looking for a http endpoint for the sub, [tag:google-sheets-api] has one.

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to integrate it with App Script?

Yes it is possible, but it will depend on whether your MQTT broker (which you've shown as myqtthub.com) allows you to create a webhook, which will be needed to forward your messages when received (usually as JSON payload) to the Google Apps Script server via http(s) using your custom Apps Script URL.

Here is an online example: https://docs.emqx.com/en/cloud/latest/rule_engine/rule_engine_web_hook.html